# Is there a way to achieve key combination (Ctrl + +) using TestCafe?

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, keypress, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have been struggling trying to get the key combination mentioned in the title (Ctrl + +).

What I have tried so far:

```
'ctrl+\+'
'ctrl+\\+'
```

Is this even supported in TestCafe?

The project I am working on uses Typescript as the primary language.

Answer (score 1):

This combination is not supported as it does not make any sense for editors:

[Press Key Action](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/press-key.html)

Please clarify where and how you are going to use it.

Alternatively, you can try using an approach from this thread: [Is it possible to simulate keypress events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Comment: It is going to be used to test a zoom action in a canvas element. Nothing related to editors.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. In this case, you can try using an approach from this thread: [Is it possible to simulate keypress events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)